# How to Redirect Pages with Query String?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to `Redirect` as seen below:

```
https://example.com/p1/p2?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2
```

to

```
https://example.com/p3/p4?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2
```

Also, I have this code in my `.htaccess` file :

```
RedirectMatch 410 ^/p1/p2&
```

I have used below code, but I just see `410 code` for that URL :

```
RewriteRule ^/p1/p2?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2$ /p3/p4?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2 [QSD, R=301,L]
```

So, I have changed `RedirectMatch 410 ^/p1/p2&` to `Redirect 410 ^/p1/p2&` , but this time I have seen `404 Code` for my `Request URI`.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following instead, replacing your existing `RedirectMatch` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/p1/p2?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2" and keep query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sort=p\.model&order=ASC&page=2$
RewriteRule ^p1/p2$ /p3/p4 [R=302,L]

# Reject all requests that start "/p1/p2&" with 410 Gone
RewriteRule ^p1/p2& - [G]
```

You don't need to repeat the query string in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (ie. `/p3/p4`), as the query string from the requested URL will be passed through unaltered by default (providing you don't explicitly set a query string on the *substitution* yourself).

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Change to 301 if this is intended to be permanent, but only once you have confirmed that it's working OK. Clear your browser cache before testing.

> I have used below code, but I just see 410 code for that URL

It's unclear why you were seeing a 410 response unless "something else" was triggering this. Your existing `RedirectMatch` directive should not have matched.

However, it is advisable not to mix mod_alias (`RedirectMatch` and `Redirect`) with mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) directives as you can get unexpected conflicts. Different modules execute independently and at different times during the request. So, you can find that a `RedirectMatch` (or `Redirect`) directive still gets processed, even though an earlier `RewriteRule` directive has rewritten the request.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/p1/p2?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2$ /p3/p4?sort=p.model&order=ASC&page=2 [QSD, R=301,L]
> ```

This won't actually do anything. There are a number of issues with this directive (in order of severity):

- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. So this *pattern* will simply never match. (To match the query string, you must use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable - as shown above).
- You have a *space* in the middle of the *flags* argument. This would result in a 500 Internal Server Error if processed ("Invalid flags").
- The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag is redundant.
- No need to repeat the same query string in the *substitution* (ie. target URL) as this would be copied as-is from the requested URL by default.

> So, I have changed `RedirectMatch 410 ^/p1/p2&` to `Redirect 410 ^/p1/p2&`, but this time I have seen 404 Code for my Request URI.

`Redirect 410 ^/p1/p2&` would not do anything because the `Redirect` directive does not accept regex, unlike the `RedirectMatch` directive. But, as noted above, these directives belong to the same module (mod_alias) anyway, so changing this to `Redirect` serves no purpose in this instance.

You were likely getting a 404 because "nothing" was happening.